# 7 Hours to Kill in Atatürk

Tags: transit, turkey, istanbul, isl, turkish-airlines

I am booked to go from Dublin to Hong Kong with Turkish airlines with a stopover in Istanbul.

There is a long layover, and I was wondering if anyone knows if I can leave the airport and head into Istanbul itself, and if so, is 7 hours long enough?

Comment: yes. The majority of the questions tagged Istanbul are about this - whether you need transit visas, the links to pages for the free tour Turkish airlines provides, and so on, are all in existing answers. Take a look and if you still have questions after that, please edit this question to be more specific about your concerns.